# Deploy Meteor app to Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, meteor

I'm new to GAE and I'm already tired and bored about it... But I'm forced to use it so I have no chance...

So far i followed something like 4 different tutorials. None of those is working... Neither is going to be close to work.

I tried now a 5th solution: [this one](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-a-meteor-app-on-google-app-engine-97d340c63576)

Except the last command: `gcloud preview app deploy` that was failing and I replaced with `gcloud beta app deploy`... Something is started to be deployed but I knew the error was just behind the corner... Indeed:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.app.deploy) Error Response: [10] Cloud Container build is not complete.
```

Guys, please... A simple thing like an empty app deployment can not be so difficult... I did in 10 seconds on Heroku and I'm trying since 3 hours to GAE...

Can you please help me doing it?

What I have so far? An empty Meteor App showing `Hello World` and a DB on mLab linked in the configuration exactly like in the guide linked above. Nothing more. It fail. Always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct deployment command is `gcloud app deploy`. Looks like you're reading out of date blog posts. The documentation shows the correct commands for deploying. There is also a [Google curated tutorial that you could follow](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-meteor-on-google-app-engine).